# The eXe-SCORM generated html file has to be transparent to show the backround UIIMage view

Tags: iphone, html, scorm1.2

Hii....i am new to iPhone programming..Can anybody help me out please

i have an html which is generated by eXe tool.I need to show it on an UIImageView,created programmatically. so the html has to be transparent then the image looks like backround.

is it possible to make that html as transparent..?

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"filename"  ofType:@"html"];

    NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle   fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];



    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:

                            [readHandle readDataToEndOfFile]   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    webView.opaque = NO;

    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

    [htmlString release];


This code helped me

Thank u all...
```